# How to use DBG with a shell script program?

Tags: debugging, debug, ardour

I'm having some problems with Ardour 4 in Ubuntu Studio 14.04 (it crashes in plugin search with the message 'segmentation fault (core dumped)'. So I’m trying to create a backtrace with DBG for it (in order to find out what is the problem and send it to the Ardour Community).

DBG works with programs, it seems... But Ardour4 is a shell script, and it seems like DBG can't find it. I've tried to use `trace exec` and `trace exec-file`, but didn't work.

What I am doing:

1. In shell, going to the folder where Ardour4 is;
2. Start DBG using "dbg ardour4";
3. Starting Ardour 4 under DBG is where all the problem is. When I type "run" or "r", DBG says the file can't be found or executed.

Is there a way to use DBG for this?
Or should I use the `bash` debug (adding -x to the first line of script)?

Comment: The "Ardour debugguing guide" on their page talks about another type of debugging, using core files. I've tried using the command (in order to enable the creation of these files when a program crash), and running Ardour4 after, to create a core file... But i couldn't find that "core file" anywhere on my system either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the ardour script, all you need to do is run `ardour4 -g` and it will run the actual ardour program under *gdb*.

Then you should be able to get a stack trace when the crash occurs.